# Correct way to add Restlet 2.3 CORS

Tags: java, ajax, rest, cors, restlet

The title says it... What is the correct/recommended way of adding proper CORS support to Restlet 2.3 that implements a `ChallengeAuthenticator` to allow Pre-flight options to access header info without Authorization header?

Originally I thought I could add the `@Options` annotation to resource interface:

```
@Options
void getCorsSupport();
```

and then implement it with something like this:

```
@Override
public void getCorsSupport() {
        Series<Header> headers = getResponse().getHeaders();
        headers.set("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization, Link, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes");

        Set<String> head = new HashSet<>();
        head.add("Authorization");
        head.add("Content-Type");
        head.add("X-Requested-With");
        getResponse().setAccessControlAllowHeaders(head);

        Set<Method> methods = new HashSet<>();
        methods.add(Method.ALL);

        getResponse().setAccessControlAllowMethods(methods);
        getResponse().setAccessControlAllowCredentials(true);
        Series<Header> reqHeaders = getRequest().getHeaders();
        String requestOrigin = reqHeaders.getFirstValue("Origin", false, "*");
        getResponse().setAccessControlAllowOrigin(requestOrigin);
    }
```

What I expected to happen was that the ajax pre-flight `Options` request would be exempt the `ChallengeAuthenticator` and the above headers would be returned. Sadly this is not the case and the ajax pre-flight `Options` request is subjected to the `ChallengeAuthenticator` like everything else. This means that the request fails because it hasn't been granted its required `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Then I did some research and found it appears to be possible to register a `CorsService` with the application.

```
public class WebApi extends Application {

    public WebApi() {
        getServices().add(createCorsService());
    }
    ...



    private CorsService createCorsService() {

        CorsService corsService = new CorsService();

        corsService.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("*")));
        corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);

        corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);
        corsService.setAllowingAllRequestedHeaders(true);

        Set<String> allowHeaders = new HashSet<>();
        allowHeaders.add("Authorization");
        allowHeaders.add("Content-Type");
        allowHeaders.add("X-Requested-With");
        corsService.setAllowedHeaders(allowHeaders);

        Set<String> exposeHeaders = new HashSet<>();
        exposeHeaders.add("Authorization");
        exposeHeaders.add("Link");
        exposeHeaders.add("X-RateLimit-Limit");
        exposeHeaders.add("X-RateLimit-Remaining");
        exposeHeaders.add("X-OAuth-Scopes");
        exposeHeaders.add("X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes");
        corsService.setExposedHeaders(exposeHeaders);

        return corsService;
    }
}
```

I thought this might be a clean way to avoid having an `@Options` method for every service. However, I must be doing something wrong as this appears to do nothing at all.

Researching still further I found that there is also such a thing as a `CorsFilter` which seems to be instantiated in much the same way as the `CorsService` except this gets attached to the `Router` in the `createInboundRoot()` method. However I don't understand how it should be implemented to work in conjunction with the `ChallengeAuthenticator`.

**Addendum:**

- I found [this](https://github.com/adennie/vroom/blob/master/vroom-core/src/main/java/com/fizzbuzz/vroom/core/api/filter/CorsFilter.java) in the code suggesting that pre-flight should be handled.

Answer (score 2):

you need to set another property of the CorsService which is called "skipResourceForCorsOptions". For example:

```
    CorsService corsService = new CorsService();
    corsService.setAllowingAllRequestedHeaders(true);
    corsService.setAllowedOrigins(new HashSet(Arrays.asList("*")));
    corsService.setAllowedCredentials(true);
    corsService.setSkippingResourceForCorsOptions(true);
```

Here is the javadocs: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.3/jse/api/org/restlet/service/CorsService.html#setSkippingResourceForCorsOptions%28boolean%29

A more detailed page will be added on the user guide, at this address: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.3/core/services/cors.

Comment: This should work... but doesn't. I guess there is a bug. Using `getServices().add(CorsService)` does not add any headers to the response! Adding `setSkippingResourceForCorsOptions` does in fact cause the resource to be skipped but none of the headers specified in the service are in the response regardless of whether I use `setSkippingResourceForCorsOptions`.  I tried it in 2.3.4 and 2.3.5.

Comment: It seems to only add the headers when an `Origin:` header is present in the request, otherwise you don't need CORS apparently. So, works as expected I guess.

Comment: yes, we consider this header is mandatory, even if is the specification is not clear about that. At least most browsers set it.